# Complex Integration

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, complex, integral-equations

There are some sequential functions:

```
e[t_] :=(E^(-t^2)) Cos[0.1 t];
a[t_] := Integrate[e[x], {x, 0, t}];
p[t_, tau_]:=Integrate[a[x],{x,t-tau,t}];
s[t_, tau_] := Integrate[(a[x])^2,{x,t-tau,t}]+ (1-(p[t,tau])^2)tau;
```

Although there are numeric values for `s[t,tau]` for example `s[2, 1] // Chop` is equal to 1.0008 but its integration (as will be shown below) does not have an answer.

```
test[t_]:=I*Integrate[E^(-I s[t,x]),{x,0,1}];
```

I mean the `test[2]//N` does have an error which could not be removed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are almost certainly going to need to evaluate `test` numerically, so let's just use `NIntegrate` from the start.

```
Clear[e, a, p, s, t]
e[t_] := (E^(-t^2)) Cos[0.1 t];
a[t_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[e[x], {x, 0, t}];
p[t_?NumericQ, tau_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[a[x], {x, t - tau, t}];
s[t_?NumericQ, tau_?NumericQ] := 
  NIntegrate[(a[x])^2, {x, t - tau, t}] + (1 - (p[t, tau])^2) tau;
test[t_?NumericQ] := I*NIntegrate[E^(-I s[t, x]), {x, 0, 1}];
test[2]

(* Out: 0.605924 + 0.731384 I *)
```

The use of `_?NumericQ` in this context is common enough to have an [entry in our `common pitfalls question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/26037#26037).

Comment: To maintain as much accuracy/precision as possible, I recommend that the OP use `Cos[t/10]` in definition of `e` and only use `NIntegrate` when necessary, i.e., for `s` and `test`. For efficiency, use `Set` (`=`) rather than `SetDelayed` (`:=`) for definitions of `e`, `a`, and `p` (after `a` and `p` are returned to `Integrate`).

Comment: With thanks to Mark, his suggestions have been so useful. Thanks a bunch for that. the problem of the integration has been solved. However, at this time, I do not have a clear interpretation of the outcome on which I must check its correctness with the main subject. Moreover, Bob's recommendation has substantially and incredibly increased speed of calculation. So much thank to Bob.